# Erro na folha de estilo sass

Tags: sass

Olá, 
Eu estava escrevendo os estilos para minha pagina home,tudo estava funcioando perfeitamente, até aparecer um erro no gulp.

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
   sass\organisms\_header.sass
Error: Invalid CSS after "...in: 35px 0 0; }": expected "}", was "{"
    on line 22 of sass/organisms/_header.sass
    margin: 35px 0 0; } {
```

Estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver esse erro, Podem me ajudar ?

ARQUIVO HEADER.SASS

```
header 

min-height: 540px

background:
    image: url('../images/slide-pag-inicial.jpg')
    position: top center
    repeat: no-repeat
    //attachment
    size: cover

.logo
    float: left
    margin: 30px 0 0
    img
        width: 118px
        height: 59px


.links
    float: right 
    margin: 35px 0 0

     nav
        +breakpoint($tablet)
                display: none
        +breakpoint($celular)
                display: none
        ul
            li
                display: inline-block
                margin: 0 20px 0 0
                a
                    color: $branco
                    text-transform: uppercase


h1,
p
    color: $branco
    text-align: center
    text-transform: uppercase
```

Comment: Posta o código do arquivo Header.sass

Comment: Acabei de postar

Answer (score 0):

Reveja seus arquivos `sass`, em algum deles contém este cód `margin: 35px 0 0; } {`
Remova a abertura de chave `{` que é para funcionar.

*Não localizei este código no que você colocou na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente consegui, o problema foi resolvido simplesmente escrevendo a linha novamente kkkkk Obrigado pela ajuda Bruno

Comment: Mas foi o que eu te falei? Em relação à chave ?